# How to count groups string input with same character

Tags: java, string, character, grouping

this code is about Too Many Tabs code.
URLs are considered equal if the domains are exactly the same, e.g. google.com and google.co.id are different

Example input

1. google.com google.co.id facebook.com facebook.com/profil
2. facebook.com/faq facebook.com/search facebook.com facebook.com/profil

Example output

1. 3
2. 1

For the first test case, it will contains and count as 3 groups

1. google.com
2. google.co.id
3. facebook.com

For the second test case, it will contains and count as 1 group

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class CountGroup
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input = "google.com google.co.id facebook.com facebook.com/profil";
     // String input = "facebook.com/faq facebook.com/search facebook.com facebook.com/profil";
     
     
        String[] arrinput = input.split(" ");

        ArrayList<String> finalin = new ArrayList<>();

        Set<String> finalinput = new HashSet<String>();
 


        for (String str : arrinput) 
        {
            finalin.add(str);
        }

        for (String str : finalin)  //[facebook.com,google.com.google.co.id,facebook.com/id] 
        { 
            if(!(str.contains("/")))
            {
                finalinput.add(str);
            }
        }
        for (String str : finalinput) 
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println(finalinput.size());      
    }
}
```